# Is it true that $\inf\{\|x+y\|:x\in X, y\in Y\}\le\inf\{\|x\| +\|y\|:x,y\in X\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space. Is it true that $\inf\{\|x+y\|:x,y\in X\}\le\inf\{\|x\| +\|y\|:x,y\in X\}$?

I need it in order to finish a proof. It seems easy, but I don't see the proof. Could anyone please help?

Comment: What is a closed normed space?

Comment: Seems to follow straight from triangle inequality.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oops, my bad! I added more than I needed. I'll change it. It had to do with a closed subspace of a normed space, but I didn't remove the 'closed' for whatever reason.

Comment: If $X$ is a normed space, then both sides are $0$, so the inequality ${}\le {}$ is true

Comment: @PotemkinMetroCard Really? How can it be so direct?

Comment: this inequality holds trivially. I suggest checking your proofs for errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\nu=\inf \{\|x+y\|:x,y\in X\}$ and pick $x,y\in X$ arbitrary. Then $$\nu\leq \|x+y\|\leq \|x\|+\|y\|$$ This shows $\nu$ is a lower bound of $\{\|x\|+\|y\|:x,y\in X\}$. Therefore $$\nu \leq \inf \{\|x\|+\|y\|:x,y\in X\}$$ and we're done.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for answering!